# Fixed Positioning Resets itself after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar that is only activated on click of the menu button. It is fixed positioning and works normal on first scroll if you do not click it.However if you click on it, the button resets its positioning and goes all the way back to the top of the page. This is only evident on Chrome and Firefox and  strangely works as intended in IE11. Any Help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NCyL4/

```
div.mobile-only {
visibility: visible;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: auto;
right: auto;
margin: 1em;
height: 2em;
z-index: 10;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the `transform: translate(0px);` applied to the **parent** (`#sb-site`).

A workaround would be to set `transform: none` instead.
Replace a line in the Slidebars plugin (l:134 in your fiddle) :

```
if (u === "translate") {
    A.css("transform", E === "0px" ? "none" : "translate(" + E + ")")
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked nicely. Hope it doesn't break anything else.

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-transform: translate(0px);` in parent element of fixed positioned menu button is overriding position of its child. So you should remove it from the parent. I found it after fast check. I don't know if it's bug but try to deal with it.